# Can't create or delete Files in Ubuntu except in Ubuntu partition

Tags: permissions, chown

I am new to Ubuntu and I don't know anything about Ubuntu. Now I am facing a problem that **I can't create a folder or delete them in Ubuntu except in Ubuntu partition**.I searched the internet and tried this command

```
sudo chown -R username:username /partition/mount-point
```

I used

```
sudo blkid
```

command to get the label name and part UUID.output of this command is:

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="DAE2797CE2795DA7" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="228d58b5-010a-490c-92f8-b141e870de99"
/dev/sda2: UUID="207B-E6AB" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="1c103e28-a020-4a3e-8031-c5cfb7aa6ba0"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="Asus" UUID="468E7FD18E7FB84F" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="1fd2c0cd-4cf2-4eee-8f31-b69d45a493b7"
/dev/sda5: UUID="32153a5f-e2e9-4a60-b1b9-1c0916a7144e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e2e83251-7c55-47b7-8e33-f0e04bd2b34d"
/dev/sda3: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="08cdb3d0-7967-4b79-a51b-24eba1bc0bd8"
```

So  I tried the above-said command customized to:

```
sudo chown -R kizhakkayil:kizhakkayil /media/"1fd2c0cd-4cf2-4eee-8f31-b69d45a493b7"
```

And the output is

```
chown: cannot access '/media/1fd2c0cd-4cf2-4eee-8f31-b69d45a493b7': No such file or directory.
```

I also tried this command:

```
sudo chown -R kizhakkayil:kizhakkayil /media/Asus
```

The ouput is

```
chown: cannot access '/media/Asus': No such file or directory
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `lsblk` to get the correct mountpoint

Comment: Why can't you create a file in Ubuntu, what error message do you receive ?

Comment: So you have an NTFS partition with the label "ASUS" on your hard disk, and you want to access it from Linux. I think that the partition is not automatically mounted (at least on my system it's not). What does the command "mount" say?

Comment: @Ajsal if this fixed your issue, could you mark me as answer?

Answer (score 2):

## Solution via windows boot

I'm guessing you have a windows dual boot?

Windows hard locks any and all NTFS partitions on your computer's hard drives before shutdown/reboot/hibernate. it's annoying and allows windows to boot a couple milliseconds faster.

if those milliseconds aren't imperative to your survival once booted up in windows open up a admin CMD :

- <kbd>Win</kbd>
- <kbd>C</kbd><kbd>M</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>
- <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

then type : `powercfg -h off`

enter, reboot into ubuntu. then you should be free to create/delete/modify windows documents and files.

## Solution on ubuntu-only

If you HAD a windows dual-boot and booting windows is no longer an option, then follow [this guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/236807/how-to-mount-your-windows-10-or-8-system-drive-on-linux/) : starting from : "Have Linux Remove the Hiberfile.sys File"

cheers! :)